# two digit year as primary key in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, primary-key

I have a table with these columns:

```
ID int,
d date
```

Now what I need is to define the primary key in such a way that ID would be unique for each year; meaning that there can not be two same IDs in 2004, but it is possible to have two same IDs in two different years.

Like:

```
insert into myTable values(1, '1-1-2004'), (1, '1-1-2005')
```

but not like:

```
insert into myTable values(1, '3-1-2005'), (1, '1-1-2005')
```

I tried this:

```
primary key(ID, datepart(YY, d))
```

but I get syntax error.

Comment: Any particular reason why it needs to be a primary key? Or does it just need to be unique?

Comment: `primary key(ID,datepart(YY,d))` is not an SQL command. Or did you have something more there? Care to tell us what the “syntax error” message is?

Comment: Being unique is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this, if you can alter the table structure, is to add a persisted computed column for the year part, and then add a primary key for (id, computer_col), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    d DATE NOT NULL, 
    y AS DATEPART(YEAR,d) PERSISTED NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id,y)
    )
```

I'm not saying this is a good solution in any way, but it should work. Using a trigger on insert or a check constraint might be better.

Using your test data this will allow the first insert statement, but disallow the second as it violates the primary key constraint.